# To advocate the act of not doing something

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that gives the same meaning as **advocate** below, but with a negative twist:

> He advocates *not doing* drugs.

I want to present this better, and emphasize that "He" stands behind (i.e. advocates) not doing drugs.

This sentence, for example, does not work:

> He *recommends* not doing drugs.

**Edit:** To be clearer, ideally it would read as if he physically worked against it, like (I'd say) *advocate* implies.

Comment: *Anti-drug activist?*

Comment: You can also *champion* a cause you believe in.

Comment: Not doing something is not “an act”. I think you must mean “To advocate against doing something”.  So are you looking for some synonym of “advocate against” then?

Comment: Okay, this is awkward. My brain thought that *advocate against* couldn't possibly work in this context. I'll go have a coffee now. Thanks everybody.

Comment: To me, the answer would be "discourage" (i.e., He discourages doing drugs.).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If he actively talks people out of drugs, or similarly works towards the cause as you seem to imply, continue to use the word *advocate* with the negation *following* it:

> He ***advocates against*** doing drugs.

While on the topic, a different phrase set may also work well. '*Doing drugs*' is informal/ slang; *drug abuse* might be more formal.

> He advocates against ***drug abuse***.

Answer (score 3):

How about "condemn"? "Proscribe"? "Denounce"?

Answer (score 1):

He opposes the use of drugs.

He disapproves of drug use.

**UPDATE**

He campaigns against drug use.

He discourages against the use of drugs.

He is a vocal opponent of drug use.

He is critical of those who use drugs.

He fights against drug use.

He is an advocate of the War on Drugs.

He is a champion of the anti-drug movement.

**UPDATE**

He advocates drug abstinence.

Comment: I think I was a little unclear above. Advocating something suggests that the *advocate* is actually working for what he advocates. My "negative advocate" would therefore work against. So disapproval and opposition is a little more passive than what is my goal.

Comment: Advocates drug abstinence?

Comment: I think very few people would include the word *against* in *"He discourages **against** the use of drugs"*. I've never heard that usage before, but it sounds a bit archaic.

Comment: @FumbleFingers 23,800 matches on google for "Discourage against" and 6,170 for "Discourages against". Doesn't sound archaic to me, perhaps its more common in certain regions.

Comment: @Baz: If it doesn't sound at least a *bit* odd to you I suppose very likely there's a regional difference. I was overstating when I said *I've **never** heard that usage before* - I think I probably just ignore what I see as the superfluous word. But Google Books has 2470 hits for *"discouraged having"*, and only 3 for *"discouraged **against** having"*, which I think clearly indicates that *most* people don't use it.